# EJB Spec 3.1 stateful conversional state

Tags: ejb, stateful-session-bean

I am new.

I don't understand the follow step of EJB 3.1 specification (Section 4.2)

The conversational state of a stateful session object is defined as the session bean instance’s field values, its associated interceptors and their instance field values, **plus the transitive closure of the objects from these instances’ fields reached by following Java object references.**

Any one, could show me ad example, please?

Thanks in advance

Mauro

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. If a session bean has an instance field of type Foo, where Foo has instance fields bar and kaz, then the values in bar and kaz are also part of the state.

Comment: thanks Mike, is really simple; my English, however, is very bad